# Heroku Unable to parse mongodbURL using Environment Variable

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, deployment, config

I am using config package to set my environment variable in my node.js application with mongo db cloud

Heres my config/development.json

```
{
  "jwtPrivateKey": "devKey",
  "db": "mongodb+srv://user:password@app-0n0nh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

And Heres my config/production.json

```
{
  "jwtPrivateKey": "PRIVATE_KEY",
  "db": "DB_URI"
}
```

When I deploy my application to HEROKU, And if I set NODE_ENV=development(from heroku dashboard), the database is connected successfully.

But If I set NODE_ENV=production,
the deployment is failing with error

```
Uncaught Rejection:-
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442256+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442258+00:00 app[web.1]: at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:505:21)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442260+00:00 app[web.1]: at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:195:3)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442261+00:00 app[web.1]: at connectOp (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442263+00:00 app[web.1]: at executeOperation (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:416:24)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442264+00:00 app[web.1]: at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:175:10)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442266+00:00 app[web.1]: at Promise (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:612:12)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442268+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442269+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:609:19)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442271+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:321:15)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442272+00:00 app[web.1]: at module.exports (/app/startup/db.js:9:6)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442273+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:7:24)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442275+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442276+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442278+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442279+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442281+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442282+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442283+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442285+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
2019-08-03T06:36:06.442928+00:00 app[web.1]: error: Exiting...
2019-08-03T06:36:08.229907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-08-03T06:36:08.153648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-08-03T06:36:08.154046+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
```

I have set DB_URI to the same string in the config/development.json

[image: Proof]

Heres my server connecting excerpt

```
module.exports = function() {
  const url = config.get("db");
  mongoose
    .connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => winston.info("Database Connection Successful"));
  mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
  Fawn.init(mongoose);
};
```

My guess is development config is working because the dbURL is enclosed in double-quotes and so I changed my Heroku's DB_URI to

```
"mongodb+srv://user:password@app-0n0nh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

instead of

```
mongodb+srv://user:password@app-0n0nh.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But still I am getting the same error.
Please Help

Comment: Is the double `.json` extension in config name `config/production.json.json` just a typo here or do you really have it like that?

Comment: it's a typo, my bad

Comment: Your development file contains a literal connection string, but your production one contains the name of an environment variable. Do you have any logic to actually load the _value_ of that environment variable? (FWIW I recommend using environment variables in development too.)